# paper-toast not firing events

Tags: javascript, polymer, dom-events, polymer-1.0, paper-elements

I am struggling to hook into some of paper-toast events.

```
  var toaster = document.querySelector('#infoToast');
  toaster.addEventListener('iron-overlay-closed', function(e) {
    console.log(e);
  });
  toaster.open();
```

I expected to see a console.log of the event as soon as the toaster was closed, but nothing happens. However, if I hook into `iron-announce`, the event fires correctly.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The Dart wrapper contains an outdated JS paper-toast element version which doesn't use `iron-overlay-behavior` and therefore the events aren't fired.
I'm also waiting to for an updated version to be published.